# What are the rules for function returning pointer in c++ did I miss something in my code?

Tags: c++

I want to create a function which generates an array(filled with random numbers) of the size I give as an input and the function returns the address of the first element of the generated array. I wrote the code as best as possible without any errors or warning. But at the runtime, the program crashes. I try to debug it but the debugger also froze and do nothing. I think the problem is in returning the pointer. Please help.

```
     #include<iostream>
     #include<cstdlib>

    using namespace std;

    int** the_gen(int num)
    {

          srand(1000);
          int *ptr= new int(num);
              int** const dptr=&ptr;

          for(int i=0;i<num;i++)
          {
           *ptr= rand();
            ptr++;      

          }
              return dptr;

    } 

    int main()
       {
          cout<<"Size of array:"<<endl;
          int size_of_array;
          cin>>size_of_array;

          int **a;

          a=the_gen(size_of_array);

          for(int i=0;i<size_of_array;i++)
         {
                 cout<<**a<<",";
                 a++;
         }

    }
```

Comment: `int** const dptr=&ptr;` is a bug because `ptr` is a local variable which goes out of scope. You end up returning a pointer to the variable that no longer exits.

Comment: @drescherjm is it? It's allocated with `new`. Maybe it's the contents of ptr that doesn't go out of scope?

Comment: ***Maybe it's the contents of ptr that doesn't go out of scope?*** Yes `ptr` goes out of scope. `dptr` points to `ptr` which is invalid when `ptr` goes out of scope.

Comment: ptr does go out of scope so how should I correct this?? I can't come up with an idea.

Comment: hey everyone thanks, I got this. I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you were using int** unnecessarily. only need to use that if you're creating an array of int pointers or a 2d array of int's:
the following code does what you're after i think:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstdlib>

using namespace std;

int* the_gen(int num)
{

    srand(1000);
    //edit
    int *ptr = new int[num];
    int* const dptr = ptr;

    for (int i = 0; i < num; i++)
    {
        *ptr = rand();
        ptr++;

    }
    return dptr;

}

int main()
{
    cout << "Size of array:" << endl;
    int size_of_array;
    cin >> size_of_array;

    int *a;

    a = the_gen(size_of_array);

    for (int i = 0; i < size_of_array; i++)
    {
        cout << *a << ",";
        a++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the insight, you are right about the int**, but the program still crashes when I give input(size of array greater the 5).

Comment: are you sure? i tested it with size = 100 without a problem

Comment: `new int(num);` this will not create array

Comment: hmm missed that. i wonder why its working then :/ edited and fixed code

Comment: ***i wonder why its working then*** Sometimes with undefined behavior you are unlucky and the code appears to work.

Answer (score 0):

I think returning pointer is always bad idea, we should take memory pointers as a parameter as the follow

```
void the_gen(int num, int** arry)
{
  srand(1000);
  int *ptr = new int[num];
  *arry = ptr;

  for (int i = 0; i < num; i++)
  {
    ptr[i] = rand();
  }    
}

int main()
{
  cout << "Size of array:" << endl;
  int size_of_array;
  cin >> size_of_array;

  int *a;
  the_gen(size_of_array, &a);

  for (int i = 0; i < size_of_array; i++)
  {
    cout << a[i] << ",";
  }
}
```

Comment: `new int(num);` this will not create array

Comment: Thank you very much, these silly mistakes of mine always cause me a lot of pain.